# TreeMap<String, String> to json

Tags: json, rust

I have the following code:

```
extern crate serialize;

use std::collections::TreeMap;
use serialize::json;
use serialize::json::ToJson;
use serialize::json::Json;

fn main() {
  let mut tree_map = get_tree_map(); // : TreeMap<String, String>

  let mut tree_map2 = tree_map.iter().map(|k, v| (k, v.to_json())); //error the type of this value must be known in this context
  let json1 = json::Object(tree_map2);
}
```

I want to convert `tree_map` to json. I tried to do it by converting it to `TreeMap<String, Json>` but failed. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you have the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264841/converting-json-to-treemapstring-string

Comment: Which output do you have when using TreeMap<String, json::Json> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure you passed to `map` takes two parameters, but it should take a single parameter that is a tuple type, because `iter()` returns an iterator over tuples (see [Trait Implementations on Entries](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/tree_map/struct.Entries.html#implementations)). Change `|k, v|` to `|(k, v)|` to fix this. (I found this by adding explicit type annotations on `k`, `v`: the compiler then complained about the closure not having the right number of parameters.)

There are some other errors however. Instead of using `iter()`, you might want to use `into_iter()` to avoid cloning the `String`s if you don't need the `TreeMap<String, String>` anymore. Also, you should add `.collect()` after `.map(...)` to turn the iterator into a `TreeMap`. The compiler will automatically infer the type for `tree_map2` based on the requirements for `json::Object`.

```
fn main() {
  let mut tree_map = get_tree_map(); // : TreeMap<String, String>

  let mut tree_map2 = tree_map.into_iter().map(|(k, v)| (k, v.to_json())).collect();
  let json1 = Json::Object(tree_map2);
}
```